# Point domain to a third party while retaining control over email

Tags: domains, dns, email

I own a domain and I need to point the domain to another domain which I don't own. I'm a contractor for the other company.  The want me to do it, but I want to retain autonomy with regards to email for the domain.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your registrar has a feature for a  301 Permanent Redirect. If not, use the following code in the .htaccess on the root of your site to accomplish the same effect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This really is the simplest, and safest route.   If concerned about resources, depending on how your DNS is managed, you could change the pointer for the host (A/AAAA record), but keep say ..  mail.olddomain.com .. as your mx, dkim, and spf pointed to your current mailserver.

Answer (score 0):

Lets clarify you own exampleA.com, and want to point it to exampleB.com. Ok so forward the domain you own exampleA.com to exampleB.com in your registrars account. Emails aren't affected unless you start changing MX records.